# ¿Cómo hacer que un encendedor prenda un cigarrillo?

Tags: python, poo

Me gustaría que la clase llamada "Encendedor" interactúe con la llamada "Cigarrillo" y logre que este se prenda. Esto es lo que tengo escrito hasta ahora.

```py
class Cigarrillo:
    marca = "Malboro"
    sabor =  "Neutro"
    país =    "Argentina "
    prendido = False
 
    def __init__(self, marca, sabor, país ):
        self.marca = marca
        self.sabor = sabor 
        self.país = país

class Encendedor:
    def encender (self) :
        self.prendido = True
    
    
habano = Cigarrillo("habano", "neutro" , "cuba")



if habano.prendido == True:
 print("el habano está prendido")
else:
    print("está apagado")
```

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: La acción para encender el cigarrilo es, encender el encendedor, acercarlo al cigarrillo, y encenderlo si es que no está encendido. Me suena a una función llamda encender cigarrilo o algo asi... pero suena a una pregunta basada en opiniones ademñas.

Comment: y por qué `encendido` es un atributo de clase y no de instancia??? si vas a prender un cigarrillo solo se debe prender el que se acerca al encendedor, no toda la cagetilla!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un encendedor no está asociado a nada en particular; su única misión es producir calor.

Un cigarro necesita una fuente de calor para funcionar. Esta puede ser una llama, una brasa, un metal al rojo o simplemente el calor del Sol.

Definimos que un objeto capaz de encender un cigarro es cualquiera que implementa dos métodos:

- `encender`, que activa el mecanismo.
- `apagar`, que lo desactiva.

Por su parte, la clase base `Fumable`, de la cual deriva `Cigarrillo`, `Pipa`, `CigarrilloElectronico`, `Bong` y `Huiro` define el método `aplicar`, que recibe un *encendedor*.

Cada clase vera si el encendedor es del tipo apropiado y, en tal caso, lo aplica, produciendo algún efecto (como apagarlo si uno aplica el dedo).

En esta implementación, `aplicar` pregunta si el elemento recibido tiene las dos funciones requeridas, y en tal caso proceda a encender el cigarrillo (marcando su estado) y luego apaga el encendedor, para evitar incendios.

```
class Cigarrillo:
    marca = "Malboro"
    sabor = "Neutro"
    país = "Argentina "
    prendido = False

    def __init__(self, marca, sabor, país):
        self.marca = marca
        self.sabor = sabor
        self.país = país

    def aplicar(self, elemento):
        if hasattr(elemento, 'encender') and hasattr(elemento, 'apagar'):
            elemento.encender()
            self.prendido = True
            elemento.apagar()

class Encendedor:
    def encender(self):
        self.prendido = True

    def apagar(self):
        self.prendido = False


habano = Cigarrillo("habano", "neutro", "cuba")
encendedor = Encendedor()

if not habano.prendido:
    habano.aplicar(encendedor)

if habano.prendido:
    print("el habano está prendido")
else:
    print("está apagado")
```

produce:

```
el habano está prendido

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu clase `Encendedor` debe tener un método, por ejemplo llamado `encender` que reciba  como parámetro un objeto de tipo `Cigarrillo`.

```py
class Cigarrillo:
     #todos estos atributos corresponde a un solo cigarrillo por lo que deben ser de instancia
    def __init__(self, marca, sabor, país ):
        self.marca = marca
        self.sabor = sabor 
        self.país = país
        self.prendido = False

class Encendedor():
    def __init__(self, marca="encendedor"):
        self.marca = marca

    def encender(self, cigarro):
        if type(cigarro)==Cigarrillo:
            cigarro.prendido = True
            return
        raise ValueError("el objeto no es de tipo Cigarrillo")
```

Ahora lo único que hacemos es crear la instancia de cada clase (Para el encendedor solo hace falta una para todo el programa) y posteriormente encendemos el cigarrillo.

```py
habano = Cigarrillo("habano", "neutro" , "cuba")

encendedor = Encendedor()
encendedor.encender(habano)
print(f"el cigarro está {'encendido' if habano.prendido else 'apagdo'}")
```

Comment: En el `__init__` de la clase Cigarrillo estás inicializando una variable local que no usas en ningún momento: `prendido = False`. No habrás querido decir `self.prendido = False`?

Comment: muchas gracias, se me pasó. Tuve que escribir la respuesta en el mismo editor que da SO y no en el mio >_<